# How can i display 50 or 100 results of Bing News API

Tags: api, azure, search, bing, bing-news-search-api

The following code is not returning 50 results of news. I am using
    `&count=50&offset=0` but is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news';

$term = $_GET['q'];
$site = '(((site:aaa.com+OR+site:bbb.com)+OR+site:ccc.net)+OR+site:ddd.com)';


function BingNewsSearch ($url, $key, $query, $site) {

$headers = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n";
$options = array ('http' => array (
                      'header' => $headers,
                      'method' => 'GET' ));

// Perform the Web request and get the JSON response
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url . "?q=" . 
urlencode($query).'+'.$site.'&cc=CR&setLang=es&count=50&offset=0', false, 
$context);


// Extract Bing HTTP headers
$headers = array();
foreach ($http_response_header as $k => $v) {
    $h = explode(":", $v, 2);
    if (isset($h[1]))
        if (preg_match("/^BingAPIs-/", $h[0]) || preg_match("/^X-MSEdge-/", $h[0]))
            $headers[trim($h[0])] = trim($h[1]);
}

return array($headers, $result);
}

print "Searching news for: " . $term . "\n";

list($headers, $json) = BingNewsSearch($endpoint, $accessKey, $term, $site);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. 1) The endpoint should have **/search** at the end, 2) You are trying to restrict results to aaa, bbb, ccc, and ddd domains. Do you really need that? and 3) Use the **mkt** parameter rather than **cc** and **setLang** parameters. Also, **cc=CR** doesn't seem to be a correct value.

You can check out the supported markets here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Well, 1) Thank you! I found out that  using /news allows me to do domain restriction but using /news /search wont. However, count and offset works on /news/search only.... 2)Yes 3)cc brings better results for me and the documentation says: "If the languages list does not include a supported language, Bing finds the closest language and market that supports the request."....."closest" works for me.

Thank you again for quick response.